# MatPlotLib share y across entire figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is an example of a plot I am generating using Pandas and MatPlotLib.

Please note that even though I stated sharey = True in the code, the y-Axis is only shared across each row.This isn't much help to me, as I need to compare all plots against each other.

How can I use just one axis for the entire plot? I'd also ideally want that axis repeated for each plot.

Thank you!

[image]

```
    for field in chosenFields:
        for dataID in dataIDs:

            fig = plt.figure()
            subplots = [fig.add_subplot(rows, cols, subplot) for
                        subplot in range(1, len(fileNames) + 1)]

            for subplot, plot, fileName in zip(subplots, plots, fileNames):

                graphData = Build_Graphs.prepareOutputGraph(plot[0],
                                                            field,
                                                            dataID,
                                                            batchName,
                                                            segmentName)

                haveLegend = True if len(graphData.columns) < 12 else False
                subplt = graphData.plot(ax = subplot,
                                        legend = haveLegend,
                                        title = fileName,
                                        sharey = True)

                Build_Graphs.labelGraph(subplt, field, dataID, batchName, segmentName)

            plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.showMaximized()

            writeOutput(outputDirectory, field, dataID, graphData)

            plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you have one row and six columns for your subplot?  Did you find something similar to what you want in [the gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html)?

Comment: If I do that, it's going to look absolutely unreadable. Nothing, I fear. :(

Comment: It sounds like you want to plot all the series on the Same graph. OR specify the same *scale* for all the y axes in your 3x2 subplots.

Comment: If you want the same axis repeated for each, can't you set the same y axis on each plot with something like `[sp.set_ylim((ymin,ymax)) for sp in subplots]` at the end.

Comment: "specify the same scale for all the y axes". Yep. Problem, Ed, is that I don't know the ymin and ymax in advance.

Comment: You can get from the min/max value of the data you use to plot or just get the minimum and maximum for all axes. I've added an answer as easier than commenting

Comment: why not specify the figure layout explicitly and say `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, sharey=True)`. Then you can loop through the elements in `axes` and pass them to `graphData.plot()`

Comment: Hi @PaulH, `sharey` is much easier if using `plt.subplots`, although the code above used `add_subplot` and the OP wanted to repeat the axis for each plot. For completeness, I'll add your subplots method with the extra code to show axes, e.g.  (`[plt.setp(sp.get_yticklabels(), visible=True) for sp in subplots.reshape(-1)]`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the same axis range repeated for each plot, you can `get_ylim` from all existing and use global min/max to set all the axes,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Setup dummy data
fig, subplots = plt.subplots(2,3)
x = np.linspace(0,2.*np.pi,1000)
[sp.plot(x,np.sin(x)*(10*np.random.randn(1))) for sp in subplots.reshape(-1)]

#Get global minimum and maximum y values accross all axis
ygmin = 0.; ygmax = 0.
for sp in subplots.reshape(-1):
    ymin, ymax = sp.get_ylim()
    ygmin = min(ygmin,ymin)
    ygmax = max(ygmax,ymax)

#Set same axis for all subplots
[sp.set_ylim((ygmin,ygmax)) for sp in subplots.reshape(-1)]

plt.show()
```

As suggested by [paulH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552748/paul-h), this can also be done with `sharey=True` as part of `plt.subplots`. However, the y axis is hidden for anything but the first axis by default, so you need to tell `matplotlib` to show these again,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Setup dummy data
fig, subplots = plt.subplots(2,3,sharey=True)
x = np.linspace(0,2.*np.pi,1000)
[sp.plot(x,np.sin(x)*(10*np.random.randn(1))) for sp in subplots.reshape(-1)]

#Show axis on all subplots
[plt.setp(sp.get_yticklabels(), visible=True) for sp in subplots.reshape(-1)]

plt.show()
```

You can also specify `sharey="col"` or `sharey="row"` to share axes alone the column or row respectively.

Comment: I pasted this code snippet into what I've included in my answer right before plt.show(). It didn't work, even when I converted the last line to for sp in subplots: sp.set_ylim((ygmin, ygmax)). :(

Comment: Sorry, you need to use `subplot.reshape(-1)` to loop over all elements if subplots as it's 2 by 3. I've updated answer

Comment: `subplots` can take `sharey=True` and then you're done, right?