# Force pyplot subplots to use the same y-axis scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a script to plot count rates with the raw source data, background and source with background corrected that I would like to display one below the other. However, I would also like the three separate subplots to have the same y-axis limits and scale in order to aid comparison of the three. Since I will be applying it to numerous datasets, I can't really just set all three to have the same limits manually each time.

Here's a MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(11)
y1 = np.arange(1,6.1,0.5)
y2 = np.arange(11)
y3 = np.arange(4,9.1,0.5)

plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.errorbar(x, y1, yerr=0.5)

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.errorbar(x, y2, yerr=1.0)

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.errorbar(x, y3, yerr=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MatPlotLib share y across entire figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507903/matplotlib-share-y-across-entire-figure)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(11)
y1 = np.arange(1,6.1,0.5)
y2 = np.arange(11)
y3 = np.arange(4,9.1,0.5)

plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.errorbar(x, y1, yerr=0.5)
ymin, ymax = plt.gca().get_ylim()

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.errorbar(x, y2, yerr=1.0)
plt.ylim([ymin, ymax])

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.errorbar(x, y3, yerr=0.5)
plt.ylim([ymin, ymax])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hmmm... yes, that sets them all to the same scale, but in that example it cuts off some values off the top of the other two plots. I guess I could just do a test of the min and max values across the three arrays and use them to set the limits in some way (including some extra white space around them)

Comment: You can pick the auto-limits of the other 2 plots and adjust those limits with the limits of the first plot. Now you know how.